# Is $\sqrt{\log (n)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}*(\log n)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Is $$\sqrt{\log (n)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}*(\log n)$$

Comment: Simple: You try it for $n=e$

Comment: This isn't true. Why do you think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

Let's interpret $\log$ as the decadic logarithm (base = 10), and let $n = 10000$:

$\sqrt{\log (n)}=\sqrt{\log (10000)}=\sqrt{4}=2$

On the other side:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}*(\log n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}*(\log 10000)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}*4=2*\sqrt{2}$

Since $2 \ne 2*\sqrt{2}$, both terms are not equal.

If you prefer to interpret $\log$ as natural logarithm, then let $n = e^4$, and you get the same results.

Comment: In RHS if instead of \frac {1}{ \sqrt{2} } , it is 1/2, then it would be correct?

Comment: @VasuDevGarg: If you find just one single value for n that proofs, that both sides of an equation are unequal, then you did proof that the equation is wrong. With this technique you can't proof an equation as true if both sides match by accident. Even if you find trillions of single-value-proofs. If there is just one value that proofs the equation as wrong, then it is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing up several identities. The following are true:

- $\log(\sqrt{n}) = \log(n^{\frac{1}{2}}) =  \frac{1}{2} \log(n)$
- $\log(n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \log(n)$

But yours isn't true, see e.g. the other answer by @HubertSchölnast.

Comment: The rule is $\log(x^b) = b \log(x)$ right? So it shouldnt be $\sqrt{n}$ after the equal sign.

Comment: @Neutronic Yeah, I derped.